# How to match individual substring to a String in Sql?

Tags: java, sql

I am Calling a named query using Entity Manager in my main class as below

```
this.list = em.createNamedQuery(MyClass.Check_Name).setParameter("name", NAMES).getResultList();
```

And the Named query is as below

```
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = MyClass.Check_Name, query = "SELECT sc FROM sampleTable sc  where sc.name IN :name")})
```

I'm passing NAMES containing the String value ('A','B','C')

now the problem I'm facing is the sc.name column in the table consists of individual values as "A", "B", "C" but I'm comparing the column sc.name as whole in the query to NAMES variable.Hence it is returning ) result list.

How to match individual substring to a String?

Comment: You need to construct the query string using `:NAME`.  SQL doesn't accept lists as a single parameter.

Comment: number of parameter in the NAMES variable is not fixed. so can we construct such sql queries?

Comment: Use like `where ','+:name+',' like '%,'+sc.name+',%'` (ms sql string concatenation syntax).

Comment: @Serg Can you please post full Query syntax, Bcoz I'm getting error while changing the query to above suggested format

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: and also Im using SQL not MYSQL

Comment: Im Using Oracle

Comment: what is the JPA implementation that you use?

Comment: @hunter I'm using EclipseLink

Comment: try my answer, for hibernate it works, because QueryImpl specially do a instance of check for a collection. probably EclipseLink might do the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass a `List` (or any `Collection`) to setParameter method.

```
query.setParameter("name",list)
```

hibernate specially does an instance of check for collection

```
 public TypedQuery<X> setParameter(String name, Object value) {
    try {
      if(value instanceof Collection) {
        this.query.setParameterList(name, (Collection)value);
      } else {
        this.query.setParameter(name, value);
      }

      this.registerParameterBinding(this.getParameter(name), value);
      return this;
    } catch (QueryParameterException var4) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(var4);
    } catch (HibernateException var5) {
      throw this.getEntityManager().convert(var5);
    }
  }
```

other JPA implementations might have the same kind of behaviour

Comment: hey @hunter, thanks for your answer. I used your idea of passing parameter as list of strings and it worked for me, hence adding the eclipselink JPA code to your answer. thanks again:)

Answer (score 1):

JDBC has an [**Array**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html) class for the SQL ARRAY, for some usages, like [createArrayOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])).

```
Array array = connection.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", new Object[] {"A", "B", "C" });
preparedStatement.setArray("name", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you stick with NAMES being string kind of "A,B,C", I see 2 options:
1) build sql every time, no parameters

```
query = "SELECT sc FROM sampleTable sc  where sc.name IN (" + NAMES + ")"
```

which is subject to sql injection if NAMES comes from user input.

2) sql injection safe option with parameter but perfomance may be slower, optimizer can not use indexes

```
query = "SELECT sc FROM sampleTable sc where ',' || :name || ',' like '%,' || sc.name || ',%'"
```